# DateTime on mobile device not showing after row RowSelected

Tags: acumatica

Good day. I have a date selector on my mobile screen. I set the field to DateTime.Now during RowInserting and RowSelected. When I look at the field using the Mobile app the field is empty only when I save the DateTime is shown/set.

How do I display the DateTime when the Mobile page is opened?

```
    protected virtual void BNExportedDocuments_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        BNExportedDocuments doc = Documents.Current;
        if (doc == null) return;
        if ( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(doc.CollectedDate.ToString()))
        {
            doc.CollectedDate = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
```

I have the same code in BNExportedDocuments_RowInserting

then in my mobile part:

```
add screen SO304050 {
 add container "Documents" {

 add field "DocumentNo"
 add field "CollectedDate"
 add field "CollectedBy"
 add field "PhoneNo" 
 add field "PhoneNo_"
 add recordAction "SignReport"{
  behavior = SignReport
  displayName = "Sign"
  icon = "system://Pen"
 } 
 add recordAction "Save"{
  behavior = Save
  after = close
  icon = "system://Check"
}
add recordAction "Cancel" {
    behavior = Cancel
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need separate components for Date and Time in mobile app. You can refer out-of-box Task screen (`CR306020`) in Acumatica mobile app for Reminder Date and Reminder Time.

Decorate your data field with [PXDBDateAndTime](https://help-2020r1.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=0fe1d7bb-3452-b2b0-c70c-0de73c8a3c37) Attribute.

```cs
public abstract class remindAtDate: PX.Data.BQL.BqlDateTime.Field<remindAtDate> { }

[PXDBDateAndTime(InputMask = "g", PreserveTime = true, UseTimeZone = true)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Collected Date")]
public virtual DateTime? RemindAtDate { get; set; }
```

With this, DAC field can be represented in the UI by two input controls (one for date and other for time)

[image]

Comment: Hi DChhapgar, I tried implementing your solution but I can't get it working? after the change, the Date doesn't show in the mobile app anymore. Is there a step I need to still add?